# Gulp dependency looking in wrong folder

Tags: gulp, bower, video.js

TL;DR
Font's are moved to the correct folder, but referenced wrong

I have implemented VideoJs in my project using Bower, however on the front end after Gulp has compiled the static files, I'm getting errors regarding the Icon Font that is used by VideoJs.

The browser is pointed at `/dist/styles/font/vjs.woff` while the file is at `/dist/fonts/vjs.woff`

I'm running a Wordpress site with Wordpress theme Sage (https://roots.io/sage/) with `gulpfile.js` built in and I don't have a lot of experience with Gulp otherwise.

What could be missing that it's setting up these wrong URLs?

This is what it looks like in the compiled CSS:

```
src: url('font/vjs.eot');
src: url('font/vjs.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('font/vjs.woff') format('woff'), url('font/vjs.ttf') format('truetype'), url('font/vjs.svg#icomoon') format('svg');
```

**Gist**

https://gist.github.com/rkorebrits/18932bb6439b386fb4fc

p.s.
I've noticed that fonts that are referenced to a `fonts` (plural) folder are handled correctly

Comment: Can you post a gist of the gulpfile.js, or at least the portion relevant to the styles?

Comment: Thanks, I've added one

Comment: Did you check the config variable ? (Just asking...)

Comment: @nha I'm not quite sure what you're asking? `config.env` is set to "dev"

Comment: @Richard please check my updated answer. It should be just working by updating VideoJs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update!

This syntax (`!default`) has been merged to master branch after [my PL](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/pull/2571). If you change `video.js` version to master and reinstall, it should be just working.

bower.json:

```
{
  //... 
  "dependencies": {
    //... 
    "video.js": "master"
  }
}
```

**Note**: I suggest you to change it to a fixed version after a new release.

---

In Sage project, [main.scss](https://github.com/roots/sage/blob/master/assets/styles/main.scss) imports custom variables and font path via [_variables.scss](https://github.com/roots/sage/blob/master/assets/styles/common/_variables.scss).

```
// Glyphicons font path
$icon-font-path: '../fonts';
```

And then imports all bower style components. However in VideoJs project, variables are not defined with `!default` syntax like bootstrap project. This cause font path variable to be overwritten in [video-js.scss](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/src/css/video-js.scss#L4) file. All variables in this project should have been defined with `!default` syntax like:

```
$icon-font-path: '../fonts'  !default;
```

## Possible solutions:

- Change `video-js.scss` file locally and send a PR to the project.
- In your [gulpfile.js](https://github.com/roots/sage/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L208), all fonts are moved to `fonts` directory. Write additional case for VideoJs to copy its font to `styles/font`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the projects have a different assumption on the location of the resulting css file. The wordpress theme assumes it to be in a `styles` dir that is next to a directory `fonts`, meaning all references to fonts will start with `../fonts` (as defined in [_variables.scss](https://github.com/roots/sage/blob/master/assets/styles/common/_variables.scss)), now videojs assumes the css file to be itself located next to the `font` (or fonts) directory, so paths start with just `font/` (as defined in [video-js.scss](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/3abc5c66df34de2ef11b946aaef74a6daca838bc/src/css/video-js.scss)). I'd say you have to change one to match the other.